# Replacing an old light switch with a new dimmer switch

Tags: light, dimmer-switch

So I have an old light switch. The wires from the wall have 2 black, 1 red, 2 white, and 1 ground wire.
The new dimmer switch has 1 red, 1 blue, 1 black and 1 ground.
I tried all combinations but have had no success. Can you please give me the correct wiring procedure?

Comment: What do the instructions for your new switch tell you to do? How are (were) the wires from the wall connected to the old switch? Is the old switch a "3-way" switch where there are multiple switches which control the same lights?

Comment: Do you remember or have a picture on how the old switch was wired before?  Sounds like you have one cable from the panel/power and one from the light.  If you know which is which that will help.  Instructions or the make and model of dimmer switch will help.

Comment: With the wires from the wall all disconnected, do any outlets or other lights not work?

Comment: The current dimmer see with has 1 red, 1 black, 1 blue and a ground. The old switch had the 2 black wires joined together and tethered to one screw on the old switch and the red wire screwed directly on the old switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the original list of wires:

> The wires from the wall have 2 black, 1 red, 2 white, and 1 ground wire.

and the comment:

> The current dimmer see with has 1 red, 1 black, 1 blue and a ground. The old switch had the 2 black wires joined together and tethered to one screw on the old switch and the red wire screwed directly on the old switch.

you most likely have:

- Incoming cable - black hot and white neutral
- Outgoing cable - black hot, white neutral and red switched hot

which is a very common and easy to deal with situation.

The blacks are connected together at the switch so that incoming hot powers the switch and *also* goes on to another location.

You didn't mention the white wires - presumably they are connected together with a wire nut. *If they are not connected together, **STOP**.*

The red is switched hot.

Based on wire colors, the new dimmer does not need neutral.

- Connect the two black wires together with the dimmer black wire with a wire nut.
- Connect the red wire with the dimmer red wire with a wire nut.
- The white wires stay connected together.
- The blue wire *most likely* is to be used only if you have a 3-way switch setup. Cap it with a wire nut and a piece of electrical tape to make sure the wire nut stays on securely.
- All grounds together. I'm a little concerned that you only mentioned one ground wire. I *suspect* you have a metal box and one ground wire is going to a screw in the back of the box. If that's the case, leave that ground wire as is and attach the other one to the switch ground wire.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information and after making sure the power's turned off, twist the two black wires from the wall together with the black wire from the switch using a wire nut. Connect the two white wires from the wall together with a wire nut. Connect the red wire from the wall to the red wire from the switch and cap the blue wire from the switch by itself with a wire nut. Connect your ground wires together with a wire nut.

The dimmer you have could also be used as a three way switch which would then utilize the blue wire

Comment: That is exactly how I wires it! Unfortunately it did not work. Perhaps I have a bad dimmer switch?

Comment: My instructions are more detailed but basically the same. So if it isn't working with JACK's instructions then there is something else wrong. **What make/model is the new dimmer?**

Comment: You might have damaged the dimmer trying different combinations or someone else damaged it and then returned it to your home store.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   And your instructions look better.  :-)

Comment: I'm going to get a new dimmer at Lowes and will try the exact wiring you suggested. I will let you know. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: That did it, success! Thanks!

Comment: @MarcKrevo  Glad it worked out...